# Utility/tool to extract function list to CSV file

Tags: c#, powershell

I have set of .cs files. I want to extract the list of functions from those files.

I want to export the list into a CSV file with the following columns.

FileName FunctionName

Is there any inbuilt tool/utility to do that? or any other quick way (might be using powershell)?

Comment: If you put doc comments in (type ///) just before the method signature in the cs file. Then you can extract them all in to a nice littel xml file from VS, and then get to a csv from there. Alot easier than writing your own C# parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in function in PS, u need to use RegEx. If you have compiled Assembly you could use Get-Member or reflection.

This RE will probably suffice in majority of scenarios:

```
^[ \t]*(public|protected|private|static).*\([^;]*$
```

but it could be improved, for instance see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593136/regular-expressions-to-find-c-sharp-class-and-method-names) one. For 3thd party tools that can help you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996758/do-you-know-any-alternative-to-ndepend-for-architects) post.